# GIMP : Stroke path equation

Tags: gimp, bezier-curve

I am drawing rather complicated diagram in GIMP. There is number of curved lines. Is it possible to somehow get equation of stroked path? I am using that image in little program, where I need to check if point with with given X and Y coordinate is below, or above this curved line.

Image (stroked path is indicated with black arrows):

[image]

**Is it possible to get equation of stroked path in GIMP?**

Answer (score 1):

The Gimp paths are sequences of cubic [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Assuming your curve is defined with only two anchors and two tangents, you can easily write the equivalent equation if you have the coordinates of these four points.

Btw, you should really be using Inkscape for this...